# Should I provide partialed functions based on API call in Clojure?

Tags: design, functional-programming, clojure

I am designing a library to wrap an API with Clojure. The API requires user credentials to authenticate user related calls.

My first approach was to have functions that do each task the API can do:

```
(defn send-email
  [credentials email]
  (call-api credentials :email email))

(defn send-message
  [credentials message]
  (call-api credentials :say message))
```

However, I noticed that most of the functions have the same argument, `credentials`. Hence, I thought of another way to approach this. How about returning functions `partial`ed with the credentials after you login:

```
(defn authenticate
    [username password]
    (let [credentials (api-auth username password)]
      {:credentials credentials
        :send-email (partial send-email credentials)
        :send-message (partial send-message credentials)})
```

This makes it much more convenient, the user of this library does not need to add the credentials on every call.

But wait, this looks a lot like what you would do in object-oriented programming. You pass something into a function (the initializer) and you get functions (from an object) that are tailored to what you passed in.

The above could have been written as this in Java:

```
public class Api {
    private String credentials;
    Api(String username, String password) {
        this.credentials = Utils.api_auth(username, password);
    }

    void send_email(String email) {
        Utils.call_api(this.credentials, Utils.EMAIL, email);
    }

    void send_message(String message) {
        Utils.call_api(this.credentials, Utils.SAY, message);
    }
}
```

As Clojure is a *functional* programming language, I want to avoid object-oriented programming but it feels as though the whole task was meant for object-oriented programming languages.

How should I design for such an API? Which approach should I choose, or is there something I am not thinking of in my object-oriented mind?

**UPDATE**
I thought of a third way: `binding`s:

```
(def ^:dynamic *credentials*)

(defn send-email
  [email]
  (call-api *credentials* :email email))

(defn send-message
  [message]
  (call-api *credentials* :say message))
; Usage
(binding [*credentials* (api-auth username password)]
  (send-email "hello")
  (send-message "hello"))
```

However, the problem with this is that it is very easy to create erroneous code—just don't bind anything at the start. This is different from implementations of dynamic vars I have seen ([`pprint`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html)), where there is a default binding.

Comment: Wrap it in a [protocol](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols) if you want to feel more Clojurey.

Comment: @kdgregory according to the linked page, protocols are meant for abstractions. That means that it would be useful if I had more than one type of credentials... but I don't.

Comment: My point was that there was nothing wrong with what you were doing. If you feel that you need to be a functional purist, then you need to pass the credentials into every call. But Clojure isn't a language for purists (if you doubt that, think about how bindings are implemented). So do what you like.

Comment: You might also want to consider that, in the [SICP videos](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/), there's a section about implementing objects in Scheme.  For that matter, the SICP book (second edition, at least) has a 100+ page section on object modelling. That implies to me that "object" concepts were accepted in the LISP community back in the 80s, so are still OK today.

Comment: @MoonCheesez "this looks a lot like what you would do in object-oriented programming" So what?

Comment: @Goyo "As Clojure is a functional programming language, I want to avoid object-oriented programming" that's what

Comment: @MoonCheesez But why? Your code is already functional and avoiding OOP won't make it more functional. Your question seems to beg that functional and OO are at odds, which is not the case.

Comment: @Goyo Functional and OO seem to be at odds as from what I know, functional functions must be pure and OO requires objects have mutable attributes, which are not pure. If not, what would be the definition of functional and OO?

Comment: @MoonCheesez Your clojure code is pure, isn't it?

Comment: I did not put much thinking into it but it may be possible to use some kind of monad in which the credentials are part of the state that is implicitly passed through subsequent function calls. OOP is used both for representing state and for dynamic dispatch: do you need dynamic dispatch in your scenario?

Comment: Just FTR: (1) Yes, "objects" are families of partially-applied functions, usually namespaced under that object; (2) No, the partially-applied state is not required to be mutable. (3) Objects are not a problem; uncontrolled mutable state and uncontrolled effects are. You can have objects that play nice both with state (e.g. immurtable) and with effects (e.g. in a monadic way).

Answer (score 2):

> OO requires objects have mutable attributes

No, OO requires objects have attributes. There is a lot of OO code that uses objects with mutable attributes, and *also* a lot of OO code that uses objects with only *immutable* attributes.

Take a look at Java's `String` class, all the operations give you *new* `String`s, rather than mutating the content of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is "functional" enough for you but you could replace `call-api` with `call-auth-api` and in that have it obtain credentials, possibly from a duration limited store, and supply them as one of the inputs to the actual `call-api`.

Comment: I think implementing a duration limited store can increase the complexity greatly as managing the store, especially expiring the store, will require a constant checking.
Aside from that, pulling data from an external source in a function is not really functional...